# ruby on rails: Binding a view to a non database model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have bound a particular view to a non database model .

Here is the model

```
class ShelfDetailStep

  attr_accessor :leftMostBinId, :numberOfBins    


end
```

Here is the view which takes an object from the controller

```
<%=  form_for @shelfDetailObject,  :as => :ShelfDetailStep, :url => { :action  =>  "validate_random_bin" } do  |f| %>       
            <div>Enter the number of bins in the shelf  </div>
            <%= f.text_field :numberOfBins %>
            <%= submit_tag  'Enter' %>
        <%  end  %>
```

The object shelfDetailObject is created from the controller.Here just adding `<%= form_for @shelfDetailObject..%>` threw an undefined model_name error. I had to add  `<% form_for @shelfDetailObject,  :as => :ShelfDetailStep...%>` to get this working.

Why did I have to do this when code samples typically just use the objectName to bind the view to a model? This does not work when I tried to name the object as @shelfDetailStep.

Answer (score 0):

You can use active model's power. Just add the module you want for that class.

Add following lines inside ShelfDetailStep class

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
extend ActiveModel::Naming
```